# Laravel convert a string variable to jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I currently contain a variable called `$filter` which contains a dynamic string which could be `Liverpool` for example. I am wanting to convert this string to a jQuery/JS string so I can preselect the value of a select menu.

**Script**

```
  <script>
    $.name = JSON.stringify({{$filter}});

    console.log($.name);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#filter").val(string);
    });
</script>
```

**Select Menu**

```
<select class="form-select" name="filter" id="filter"> </select>
```

When I dump the value in the console I get this error

> filter_teams:261 Uncaught ReferenceError: Liverpool is not defined

How do you properly convert a Laravel blade variable to JS?

Comment: is `console.log($.name);` this printing something?  also what is `string` here?

Comment: The error would occour before the `console.log()`

Comment: Missing quotes - I would use backticks: `JSON.stringify(\`{{$filter}}\`);` or don't stringify it: `$.name = {{$filter}};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try with below way.

Just assign your laravel variable to jquery variable and try to match value with options in selectbox.

```
var string = "{{@$filter}}";

$(document).find('#filter option[value="'+string+'"]').prop('selected', true);
```

May be this way you can achieve your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`@json` blade directive](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#rendering-json):

```
<script>
    $.name = @json($filter);

    console.log($.name);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#filter").val(string);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: for some reason my phpstorm has a red line underneath between the = and the @ $.name = @json($filter); saying expression expected

Comment: do you know the reason why?

Comment: @Lowtiercoder is this in a .blade.php file and do you have the blade PhpStorm plugin installed and up to date?

Comment: Could be that PHPStorm doesn't understand, you're mixing PHP and JavaScript because in JavaScript this would be an illegal character of sorts.

Comment: yeah i have the extension installed if i call @json directly inside the content of the page it doesnt error. Seems like what shaedrich mentioned is the mixture of the languages the solution below fixed my issue but thankyou for taking the time to reply